# solr python query for defining a cutoff relevancy score

Tags: python, solr

I am trying to frame a search query in solrpy. I need documents that are above a relevancy score threshold say 100. 
I have the below query which gives me the top 50 results.

```
t = s.query('title:\"%s\" OR description:%s'%(title,desc), rows=50)
```

How do I re-frame the above query to get results above a threshold relevancy score?